# fresh lubuntu install & wireless problems

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I just installed lubuntu and the wireless connection does not work. No wireless connections show at all, but are visible on other machines.

Ethernet works fine, and in the previous version of Ubuntu I was running the wireless worked fine( don't remember the version, but was from the pre forced unity days).

the option to enable wireless is not even listed.

the wireless card in my laptop is Intel pro 2200bg in an old Sony vaio.

`iwconfig` shows "no wireless extensions"

`rfkill` does not work

I had to disable acpi to even install any of the latest distros on this machine, if that means anything.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you

Comment: acpi=off turns off wireless and several other things that are need, you should try nomodeset. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 this thread is a little old but is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the OS detected the device and perhaps your just missing a driver

```
$ sudo lspci
```

The output you see from lspci should have a line somewhere that looks somewhat like this if its been detected

```
-->  Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG......
```

You can also look at the dmesg logs for potential clues that can provide hints

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep Intel
```

Run modprobe ipw2200 to see if you have the needed driver as part of your intallation

```
$ sudo modprobe ipw2200
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that a couple of times only to find out that the laptop had an inconveniently placed wireless override switch or button which disabled the connection which for whatever reason the owner never noticed and which apparently never got bumped while using Windows (or more likely it didn't work in windows but kept the wifi on all the time)